# linux permissions issue when triyng to run nodejs script

Tags: linux, node.js, permissions

I have the following files in the folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 al al 4096 Nov 10 20:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 al al 4096 Nov 10 09:36 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 al al  163 Nov 10 20:53 1447181583
drwxr-xr-x 3 al al 4096 Nov 10 10:48 html/
drwxr-xr-x 3 al al 4096 Nov  9 23:15 node.js/
-rw-r--r-- 1 al al  144 Nov 10 20:53 query
drwxr-xr-x 3 al al 4096 Nov 10 20:27 source/
drwxrwxr-x 3 al al 4096 Nov 10 20:53 target/
```

and inside node.js i have this files:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 al al  526 Jul 20  2014 config.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 al al   19 Jul 20  2014 end.html
drwxr-xr-x 8 al al 4096 Nov  9 19:23 node_modules/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 al al 1160 Jul 20  2014 script.sh*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 al al 2889 Nov  9 23:08 server.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 al al  676 Aug 30  2014 start.html
```

the file `server.js` makes a server listening on port 9080 and than process input from `config.html` and runs `script.sh`.

the content of `config.html` looks like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:9080/config" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="config"></input>
</form>
```

but for some reason, after starting the run of the server, when i submit the data i get it to ask me for root password, and after i type it than it asks again. my user name is `al`, how can i make the `server.s` do its job without asking me for password?

this is the relevant content of `server.js`:

```
app.post('/config', function (req, res) {
    var source = req.body.data;
    var script = '/home/al/Projects/DataMining/node.js/script.sh ' + source;
    exec(script);
    addCronTab(script);
    //readFile - respon file that read..
    res.end('success');
});

app.get('/select', function (req, res) {
  selectQuery(req,function (err, guides) {
  var text = fs.readFileSync('/home/al/Projects/DataMining/node.js/start.html', 'utf8');
    if (!err && guides) {     
      text += guides;   
    } else {
      text += "NO DATA FOUND";
    }
      text += fs.readFileSync('/home/al/Projects/DataMining/node.js/end.html', 'utf8');
      res.end(text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The node.js server should he running as **al** not as the Tomcat user.

The user-specific crontab should be updated without sudo using something similar to **crontab -e** except taking your cron entry from you node.js server.

Allowing a web server to run arbitrary user-supplied commands as root is extremely dangerous and likely to lead to system compromise.